# PaintGL() call understanding

Tags: c++, opengl

I know that `PaintGL()` function is call at the same frequency that the screen's (let's say 60 times per second). But if no pixel is displayed on the screen (if another window hide the OpenGL one) the call to `PaintGL()` is no longer restrain and is called a lot much more... Which use the CPU at max and is annoying.

So, is there a way to restrain it ?

I'm using MacOS 10.9 and Qt Creator.

I don't know a lot about vsync. The fact is my software use 30% of the CPU when it's in the forground and when it's hidden, it goes up to 95%.

Comment: Are you saying that with enabled vsync your background window no longer vsync-locked? What OS/graphics driver/etc.? Are you sure vsync was enabled?

Comment: Are you sure, that your `PaintGL()` really gets called more often in this case? I don't know about Qt's internals, but normally it should not be called at all, when your window is hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't enabled vsync, frames swap as often as possible (if you haven't added artificial pause). If you pushed high load on graphics card, it is likely that your program is GPU-limited (CPU have nothing to do and standing idle waiting for GPU to finish drawing).

When your program is invisible, drawing costs close to nothing because noone sees results anyway (optimisation performed by graphics driver internally).

So, answer to your question is - enable vsync. It will lock buffer swapping interval to monitor's refresh rate, so your frame rate will never rise higher than refresh rate (in fact, it will be locked to numbers 60/30/20/etc., if your monitor is at 60 Hz). This is very useful technique that e.g. eliminates screen tearing.

Comment: And how do I enable vsync?

Comment: It is platform-dependent. Try http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39399-QGraphicsView-opengl-Vsync if you use Qt's GL initialisation.

Comment: VSYNC is not particularly useful for eliminating screen tearing anymore (in a windowed application). OS X and Windows both use compositing window managers now, you can swap your buffers at full-speed (e.g. 12,000 FPS) without VSYNC and the window manager itself will prevent tearing by only updating the window at the proper VBLANK interval. It is useful for throttling CPU/GPU utilization on an application that renders faster than the monitor can display images.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman don't know about OSX, but on windows (starting with vista) no matter what i do - i still see tearing, unless in true fullscreen mode with vsync enabled, or disabled aero somehow. Don't know about 8 tho, as i recall they removed aero, maybe things are better now. Never used compositing WM on linux so never seen tearing there (my primary env). But anyway, judging by the core technology of how vsync works - i doubt WM can map arbitrary framerate to screen refresh (and windows aero partially confirms this).

Comment: @keltar: It should be the other way around. VSYNC is unnecessary for compositing window managers, because they can use a copy of the last fully swapped front buffer image (eliminating issues with swaps that do not finish before the VBLANK interval). When you swap buffers, the framebuffer does not go straight to the display like it used to... the window manager draws the windows as a separate drawing process. In fact, on Microsoft Windows the DWM has the highest priority of any application when it comes to scheduling the GPU.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman it would require window manager to run with vsync on and a lot of copying tricks - something like emulating triple buffering. Not arguing - honestly i don't know if they do that, but my experience with windows shows quite opposite. All i was able to find on GL forums is entering true fullscreen or disabling compositing WM. And yes, i hate tearing :-(. But anyway, it is no longer question-related ^^