# OpenGL paint strange behavior on virtual machine

Tags: opengl, virtual-machine, paintevent

I develop a cross platform (Mac OS & Windows) OpenGL application. To do this I use a Mac and a virtual machine (last VMWare fusion, W7 and guest add-on).

On the Mac part, the program works as I wish, on the VM part, the `paintGL()` function is called way to often (called every 16ms on mac <1ms on VM) which totally screw my work.

Doesn't anyone know how to get the normal behavior of `paintGL()` on a virtual machine or do I really have to switch to a physical machine ?

**EDIT** : I try to enable the VSync on VMWare using this way : add `mks.vsync="1"` at the end of the vmx file but it ain't changed a thing...

Comment: How is your `paint()` function invoked? If it is coupled to Vsync, this might cause problems on VMs

Comment: @user1781290 I made a mistake, it's `paintGL()` and not `paint()`. The function is provided by [QGLWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#paintGL) and there's no mention of Vsync in the doc... Can I emulate VSync?

Comment: Then you might have a similar problem, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371561/paintgl-call-understanding

Comment: @user1781290 guess what, that's my post :) and I still don't know how to enable VSync on virtual machines

Comment: VSYNC really is not going to help you here. Typically monitors have a refresh rate of ~60 Hz, which is 16.666 ms. Even with VSYNC, if that were in fact the problem, you would be drawing > 3x too fast.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I made a mistake and type 60ms instead of 60Hz (~16ms)